# How to integrate PayPal into Aqbanking (HBCI)?

Tags: api, paypal

Since some time aqbanking supports paypal for hbci but I do not find any examples or documentation about that.

Does anyone can give me a legit example how to integrate paypal to download the current balance and also the last transactions like for any other bank supporting hbci?

Answer (score 0):

If your version of AqBanking supports Paypal, it will appear in the list of protocols for a new user alongside HBCI, EBICS, OFX and offline. Many distributions, however, do not include support for Paypal.